# XPATH expression to count number of input tags in html form

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to count the number of input tags present inside HTML forms.

I've used Selenium Web Driver (Chrome) with Python3.

**Python code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def extract_login_details(url):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    browser.get(url)

    forms = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//form')
    print(f'forms - {len(forms)}')

    for i in range(len(forms)):
        inputs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f'//form[{i+1}]//*/input | //form[{i+1}]/input')
        print(f'input tags in form{i+1} is {len(inputs)}')



extract_login_details('http://localhost:8081/selenium/test2.jsp')
```

**test2.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>

    <form action="form1" method="post" autocomplete="on" >
        <input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email1" id="email1"/>
        <input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass"/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <form action="form2">
        <input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email2" id="email2"/>
        <div><input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass2" id="pass2"/></div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Correct output**

> forms - 2
>   input tags in form1 is 3
>   input tags in form2 is 2

But when I enclose the second form inside div tag (**modified test2.jsp**), I get incorrect output.

```
<html>
<body>

        <form action="form1" method="post" autocomplete="on" >
            <input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email1" id="email1"/>
            <input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass"/>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <div>
            <form action="form2">
                <input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email2" id="email2"/>
                <div><input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass2" id="pass2"/></div>
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Incorrect output**

> forms - 2
>   input tags in form1 is 5
>   input tags in form2 is 0

Comment: Shouldn't your `<input type="submit">` be `<input type="submit"/>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use [relative XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) locator from the current [`form`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) together with [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) axis to collect all nested [`input`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) elements belonging to the current form

```
inputs =forms[i].find_elements_by_xpath("./descendant::input")
```

Full code just in case:

```
forms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//form")

print(f'forms - {len(forms)}')

for i in range(len(forms)):
      inputs =forms[i].find_elements_by_xpath("./descendant::input")
      print(f'input tags in form{i + 1} is {len(inputs)}')
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: I tried to run this on OP's modified html (where the second form is enclosed div tag) and still get the same error. Can you please try that?

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri, it was really helpful. It not only solved my problem but made the code simple and beautiful. Love it.   

Just wondering why my code did not work when the 2nd form is enclosed inside Div.